# Highlight multiple cells at once

Tags: google-sheets

Rather than colouring the cells in columns M to S manually I was looking for a way to have the cell highlighted based on the number in column T.

i.e. 6 in cell R2 should correspond to S2 being highlighted green and so on. There's about 600 rows so I don't want to do this manually!

I think I can do this with 7 different conditional formats, one per column but I was wondering if there was a smoother way otherwise googlesheets might explode on me.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using conditional formating  https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html#conditional-formatting-with-formulas ? With "Use a Formula"

Comment: Yeah, I think I can do this with 7 different formats layered on top of each other but I'm wanting to find out of there is a smoother way of doing it.

Comment: You may have a way to do with 1 formula but you have to be sure that it will be always headers "Day X". By using the formula `Substition` on your headers, you replace "Day  " by nothing and then you may need to convert the string to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it through the conditional formating like this in `M2` and then duplicated to all cells :

```
IF(VALUE(SUBSTITUTION(M$1;"Day ";)) = $T2)
```

or

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTION(M$1;"Day ";)) = $T2
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxiGui sorry I forgot to say this is a google sheet not an excel, should that matter? It's not doing anything in sheets, apologies! I'll try it in excel too and I can always just copy them over it it works there.

Comment: In this case it does not change. Just dont add the « if ». I just add that to show, because the « use formula is a « if »

Comment: @L23P if it solved your question, please set it as solved

Comment: @MaxGui Apologies for the delay, nothing changes I'm afraid! Tried removing the IF, swapping to an = neither work.

Comment: Did you start with a "=" at the begining ?
For me it works fine with for example: `=CNUM(SUBSTITUE(A$1;"Day ";)) = $G2`, applied in A2. **This formula is with french function. but works fine by me.**